# Hot restart/reload not always working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, file-watcher

I think it has something to do with this warning I keep getting from dart sdk

```
Socket error: FileSystemException: Directory watcher closed unexpectedly, path = 
'c:\Users\Saad\OneDrive\Documents\Scripts\mutanafisun'
```

I searched for a solution for it but found none.

this is my flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Active code page: 1252
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-US)   
• Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f1875d570e (4 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
• Engine revision e85ea0e79c
• Dart version 2.17.6
• DevTools version 2.12.2

Checking Java status is taking a long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android 
devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java
• Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

 [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.2.3)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools
• Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 version 17.2.32526.322
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
  (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for 
  detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.70.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.46.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the current Dart/Flutter releases, however, it should not have any material affect on your app. You should be able to continue as normal:

> When Flutter builds it modifies a lot of files on disk in a short space of time and this sometimes overflows the watcher and causes it to close. The server has code to handle this (it creates new watchers and reanalyzes from disk), however to resolve some other issues during the restart it creates some additional watchers which do not have error handling (and since the Flutter build may still be occurring, it's possible those will close for the same reason). It's not ideal that a Flutter build can touch enough files to overflow the watcher and require a restart like this, but I believe that's understood behaviour because the server has had to handle this before.

Here is a full discussion:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49286

Also see confirmation that fix has been found but not yet released:

> There is a bug in the current Dart/Flutter stable releases that can trigger this error during a build. [They] have recently fixed the issue in the Dart SDK, but it has not been released yet. The fix will show up in a future release of the Dart/Flutter SDK. Unfortunately [they] don't know of a temporary workaround.

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4077

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33458769)